# Catching signals with node.js - unexpected behaviour

Tags: json-rpc, nodejs

I'm used to catching `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` on my node.js scripts. I use `process.on('SIGTERM',function(){ <stuff> });` and I can call other functions that revert some changes before closing, or just print "you pressed ^C !", do nothing else and the script keeps running if I want to.

It doesn't work since I added web3. When I press `^C` is pauses the script and I can't do anything. I have to kill the process by pid on another terminal.

The most blocking operation is accessing data from a contract loaded in the beginning of the script. Something like:

```
valueA = mycontract.mappingA(key);
valueB = mycontract.mappingB(key);
```

This operation takes about 250ms and is repeated a lot of times, so I'm almost sure the script is on that part when I press `^C`.

I tried putting that part in a `try/catch` construct but it still won't do what is on the `catch` part.

Why is this happening ? Can I make it work or should I stop catching `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` ?

---

If you need extra info, on my process list (`ps aux`), under `node myscript.js` there is a script called `[nodejs] <defunct>`. The "state" part indicates `node myscript` is `Rl+` (Running or runnable, multi-threaded, on the foreground process group) and `[nodejs] <defunct>` is `Z+` (defunct/zombie, on the foreground).

Comment: Do you have an event listener or filter in your code? That's always on until you `.stopWatching()`.

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't use `stopWatching()` either. What is always on ?

Comment: When you filter, web3 will regularly ping the RPC node for updates. It never gives back the hand so NodeJs never considers it finished.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab If I understand correctly, if I don't filter I shouldn't have this problem ? Could it be set automatically, as an option on geth for example ?

Comment: Correct, you need to explicitly filter for it to happen.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab Do you catch interruptions ? Do you have any problems with it ?

Comment: It could be instead that one of the many calls to `.mappingA` never returns, so leaves a pending call about which NodejJs is aware.